# Can I use COUNT in a PartiQL query of a Dynamo table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, partiql

Trying all of these in PartiQL Editor. DynamoDB > PartiQL editor on the AWS site.

Query: `select count(divisionID) from "org-data-dev";`

Result: `ValidationException: Unexpected path component at 1:8:5`

Query: `select count("divisionID") from "org-data-dev";`

Result: `ValidationException: Unexpected path component at 1:8:5`

Query: `select count(*) from "org-data-dev";`

Result: `ValidationException: Unexpected path component at 1:8:5`

Query: `select divisionID from "org-data-dev";`

Result: (query succeeds)

Is it just not possible to use `COUNT` in PartiQL for Dynamo? The error is misleading in that case.

Also what is the 5 in `1:8:5` -- first line, 8th character and 5th... what? It's a 2D space, 3 coordinates makes no sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot do COUNT with DynamoDB PartiQL. You can project out just the keys and count the delivered results.

I don’t know what 1:8:5 indicates.

Comment: "I don’t know what 1:8:5 indicates." -- line position and (apparently) the length of the token causing the problem

Answer (score 3):

The 5 in `1:8:5` is the length of the substring that is causing the error.

```
select count(divisionID) from "org-data-dev";
       ~~~~~
```

Answer (score 3):

> 1:8:5 indicates 1 = line 8 = position of the character 5 = Number of
> character